# MySQL database performance degraded after data purge

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have a MySQL database that I decided to purge by removing obsolete data to save space and to improve performance by removing unnecessary data.  To my surprise, after deleting many records and optimizing the tables, the performance has degraded.  I kept a copy of the old database so I can get performance comparisons.  I am running a query three times with different filters and I find the old huge database completes the queries in 1.2 seconds (with my php profiler active) while the new purged one takes 5.7 seconds to run the exact same queries.  The query is:

```
select org_members.id
from member_calendar, days, org_members
where org_members.org_id=1
  and days.date="2017-07-02"
  and days.removed=0
  and org_members.removed=0
  and member_calendar.day_id=days.id
  and member_calendar.org_member_id=org_members.id;
```

or

```
select  org_members.id
    from  org_members
    INNER JOIN  member_calendar  ON member_calendar.org_member_id=org_members.id
    INNER JOIN  days  ON member_calendar.day_id=days.id
    where  org_members.org_id=1
      and  days.date="2017-07-02"
      and  days.removed=0
      and  org_members.removed=0
```

I used phpMyAdmin to profile the query in both dB s and the major change was that the sending data step went from 617 microseconds in the large dB to 2.2 seconds in the purged one! The other steps were incrementally longer also, but this was the huge difference.

Using explain on the query the large dB showed a different sequence from the smaller one. The two results results show that:

- the larger table orders the tables member_calendar bringing up 35943 rows without using keys and then org_members using the primary key yielding 1 row and then days using the primary key yielding 1 row.
- the purged table query is run by first getting the org_members without using the primary key and yielding 288 rows and then the member_calendar without keys yielding 32695 rows and then days using the primary key and yielding 1 row.

So, it seems like the dB has chosen a different way to run the query which is much less efficient.  The database threw away the use of the primary key in the org_members table when executing the query that filters on the primary key with the smaller database but uses it with the larger one. Any ideas on why it would do that and how to correct? Is this a general type problem that should be addressed when constructing queries???? I'm quite surprised by these results.

I am at a loss for what to do next to improve the situation on the new database.  Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What are the results of an `explain [query]`?  Are the `explain`s different for before and after the purge?  I am assuming that all the indexes are still the same.  Also, how much data was purged?  From all three tables?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, please.  Please rewrite the select to use `JOIN...ON` syntax.

Comment: I used phpMyAdmin to profile the query in both dB s and the major change was that the sending data step went from 617 microseconds in the large dB to 2.2 seconds in the purged one!  The other steps were incrementally longer also, but this was the huge difference.

Comment: Using explain on the query the large dB showed a different sequence from the smaller one.  Here are the two results:

Comment: Continuing from last entry the explain results show that the larger table orders the tables member_calendar bringing up 35943 rows without using keys and then org_members using the primary key yielding 1 row and then days using the primary key yielding 1 row.  With the purged table the query is run by first getting the org_members without using the primary key and yielding 288 rows and then the member_calendar yielding 32695 rows and then days using the primary key and yielding 1 row.  So, it seems like the dB has chosen a different way to run the query which is much less efficient.

Comment: I used this query employing JOIN syntax
`select org_members.id from org_members INNER JOIN member_calendar ON member_calendar.org_member_id=org_members.id INNER JOIN days ON member_calendar.day_id=days.id where org_members.org_id=1 and days.date="2017-07-02" and days.removed=0 and org_members.removed=0 ` and the profile showed that the sending data time was 2.5 seconds, so a slight degradation.

Comment: Further study of the explain table seems to indicate that the database threw away the use of the primary key in the org_members table when executing the query that filters on the primary key with the smaller database but uses it with the larger one.  Any ideas on why it would do that and how to correct?  Is this a general type problem that should be addressed when constructing queries????  I'm quite surprised by these results.

Comment: Please show us the `EXPLAINs`.

Comment: Here is the explain for the purged dB:
`| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| 1 | SIMPLE | org_members | NULL | ALL | PRIMARY | NULL | NULL | NULL | 288 | 1.00 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | member_calendar | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 32695 | 10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
| 1 | SIMPLE | days | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | olmc_ministry_scheduling.member_calendar.day_id | 1 | 5.00 | Using where |`

Comment: And for the large dB:
`| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |

| 1 | SIMPLE | member_calendar | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 35943 | 100.00 | NULL |

| 1 | SIMPLE | org_members | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY,org_id | PRIMARY | 4 | olmc_ministry_scheduling.member_calendar.org_member_id | 1 | 9.99 | Using where |

| 1 | SIMPLE | days | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | olmc_ministry_scheduling.member_calendar.day_id | 1 | 5.00 | Using where |`

Comment: With regards to the question that was asked about the number of records removed from the tables here is that approximate data:  `days ~ 1400, org_members ~ 1300, member_calendar ~ 3200`.  The main reason for the deletion was to save space and improve performance by reducing the number of records that the dB had to deal with.  To my surprise the performance was degraded instead of improved.

Comment: More information, hopefully helpful.  I'm totally stumped with this one!!!
When profiling with php profiler using the large dB I get 3 calls to mysqli_query each one taking .382 seconds for a total of 1.147.  Running the same script on the purged dB shows the 3 calls to mysqli_query each one taking 1.497 seconds for a total of 4.491 seconds.  What on earth could cause this type of degradation just because some rows of the dB are gone?

Comment: Continuing from last entry.  The script is performing exactly the same with each run with identical results.  My desire was to speed up performance by reducing the amount of data that had to be processed by removing obsolete info. and reducing the dB footprint.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that this is a case of "over-normalization".  In general, "continuous" things, such as dates, should not be moved into another table.  Better performance can usually be had from having the date, as a `DATE` or `DATETIME`, in the table that needs it.

Also, if you are using `ENGINE=MyISAM`, perhaps the degraded performance will prompt you to move to InnoDB.

Comment: Do InnoDB tables give an appreciable performance improvement?  I knew they offered additional features such as transactions, but had understood that they were more resource consuming.  Is that not correct?  Would you recommend altering the table to move to InnoDB engine?

Comment: Disk usage is typically 2x-3x more; otherwise performance is generally better for InnoDB.  More tips on conversion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb  .  MyISAM can get into severe fragmentation; InnoDB automatically handles it better -- hence my _guess_ about your Engine usage.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  BTW the field type for days.date is `DATE`

Answer (score 0):

Below are the few suggestions.

1. Explain both queries and check if proper indexes are used.
2. Rebuild the indexes.
3. If in this tables you are reading/inserting data simultaneously then change table engine type to innodb rather than myism as myism perform table lock which slow the select and read.